# Trouble Compiling Systemd standalone binaries

Tags: systemd

Source: systemd-stable-251: https://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable

```
wget https://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable/archive/refs/heads/v251-stable.zip
unzip v251-stable.zip 
cd systemd-stable-251-stable/
```

Using command:

```
./configure --auto-features=disabled \
            --default-library=static \
            -D standalone-binaries=true \
            -D static-libsystemd=true \
            -D static-libudev=true \
            -D link-udev-shared=false \
            -D link-systemctl-shared=false \
            -D link-networkd-shared=false \
            -D link-timesyncd-shared=false \
            -D link-boot-shared=false && make
```

Also tried with just the static libraries and with just the standalone option enabled.

Configuration:

```
  Features
enabled  : IMA, SELinux, SMACK, blkid, gcrypt, gnutls, libidn2, openssl, p11kit, xkbcommon, xz, zlib, bzip2, backlight, binfmt, coredump, environment.d, efi, firstboot, hibernate, hostnamed, hwdb, initrd, kernel-install, localed, logind, machined, networkd, nss-myhostname, nss-mymachines, nss-resolve, nss-systemd, oomd, portabled, pstore, quotacheck, randomseed, resolve, rfkill, sysext, systemd-analyze, sysusers, timedated, timesyncd, tmpfiles, userdb, vconsole, xdg-autostart, idn, polkit, nscd, dbus, glib, tpm, SysV compat, utmp, ldconfig, adm group, wheel group, gshadow, standalone-binaries, static-libsystemd(true), static-libudev(true), cryptolib(gcrypt), DNS-over-TLS(openssl)
disabled : ACL, AUDIT, AppArmor, PAM, SECCOMP, elfutils, libbpf, libcryptsetup, libcryptsetup-plugins, libcurl, libfdisk, libfido2, libidn, libiptc, microhttpd, pcre2, pwquality, qrencode, tpm2, zstd, lz4, bpf-framework, gnu-efi, homed, importd, repart, sysupdate, legacy-pkla, kmod, man pages, html pages, man page indices, compat-mutable-uid-boundaries, debug hashmap, debug mmap cache, debug siphash, valgrind, trace logging, install tests, link-udev-shared, link-systemctl-shared, link-networkd-shared, link-timesyncd-shared, link-boot-shared, fexecve, coverage
```

User defined options
auto_features                  : disabled
default_library                : static
link-boot-shared               : false
link-networkd-shared           : false
link-systemctl-shared          : false
link-timesyncd-shared          : false
link-udev-shared               : false
standalone-binaries            : true
static-libsystemd              : true
static-libudev                 : true

Shared Object:

```
# file build/udevadm
build/udevadm: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=f6b7c1a3509d45ebcafda9b49f4dd2332e786738, with debug_info, not stripped
```

I'm expecting to see an ELF executable instead of shared object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the `standalone-binaries` options says:

> also build standalone versions of supported binaries

That seems ambiguous at best. Looking at the `meson_build` file, we find:

```
        if have_standalone_binaries
                exe = executable(
                        'systemd-sysusers.standalone',

[...]

        if have_standalone_binaries
                exe = executable(
                        'systemd-tmpfiles.standalone',

[...]
```

That seems to suggest that the option only influences `systemd-sysusers` and `systemd-tmpfiles`, and indeed, when the build is complete, we see:

```
$ ls build/*.standalone
build/systemd-sysusers.standalone build/systemd-tmpfiles.standalone
```

It looks like things are operating as designed.